# Indent in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have a header with 4 buttons, I divide it into 6 columns and I want to leave the first and the last empty, and place the buttons in the center.

```
.test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

However, if I use `grid-column-start: 2`, the buttons are rearranged down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grid-column-start: 2` *only* on the first button using `button:first-child`. You have the issue as you are setting `grid-column-start` on all buttons - see demo below:

```css
.test {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.test button:first-child {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
</div>
```